# Using multiple controllers in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am building a web app that manages staff in specific companies. I have two controllers:  `Staff` and `Company`. Both controllers have standard CRUD methods.

When I access the URL `sitename/Company/Staff/CompanyId`, I would like to display all of the staff employed at that company in my Details View.

Current implementation of the `Details()` method:

```
// GET: Company/Details/1
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    Company co = db.Company.Find(id);          
    return View(co);
}
```

How can I go about modifying my current `Details()` method to support this behavior?

Comment: What about this site => http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: I have checked it out but nothing seems to fit what i need?

Comment: Not nearly enough information to give a detailed answer. Do you have a method that is hit that retrieve specific data from your db and sends it to a view (which sounds like what you're trying to do)? Can you post code?

Comment: I have posted my Details method, but i need it to show staff for each company too.

Answer (score 1):

Without the code it hard to give you precise answer, but if I understood you correctly generally for every controller you have a model which correspond to your database. So if you want to use in action data from 2 or more models you must make a join using Linq.

For the first step you create a ViewModel with company and staff:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

And after that in your controller action you should fill this ViewModel and pass to the view, so it would look something like that:

```
[Route("Company/Staff/{id}")]
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var viewModel = 
        from c in db.Company
        join e in db.Employee on c.CompanyId equals e.Id
        where c.CompanyId == id
        select new MyViewModel { Company = c, Employee = e };
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

And code in View should be like this

```
    @model IEnumerable<YourAppName.Models.MyViewModel>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
         <div> 
             <p>@item.Employee.Name</p>
         </div>
    }
```

Comment: Would doing this give me the required routing like this sitename/Company/Staff/CompanyId.  I would upload the code but im not sure what would be helpful.

Comment: @stackface I updated code using [Route("Company/Staff/{id}")], so when you enter URL sitename/Company/Staff/CompanyId you will get in this action

Comment: Thanks, i currently have a Details method in the Company controller which at the minute looks like this 
`// GET: Company/Details/1
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            Company co = db.Company.Find(id);
            
            return View(co);
        }`

So would i need to create a new method for details? or adjust it?

Comment: @stackface I updated the code, create the ViewModel, then use this ViewModel in action like above, then pass this ViewModel in View, code for you could be a little bit different(especially View), but I think you get the idea.

Comment: But by doing that wont it affect my current details method? as it currently displays all Companies found and passes co to the view.  By doing the one you provided will that mean i wont have all of the Companies listed?

Comment: If you mean the data which will be passed to view, it is will be same company as before(because it still filtered by the same Id), but joined with Employee table, so you will must use a little bit different code to access as I provided in example for View